# How to load one view/page after another when scrolled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am developing a website using Laravel Framework. In my project, I have different views/pages. For now, I'm showing them separately when clicked on the navbar. But I would like to show/append next page/view to the previous one (i.e Auto Loading or Infinite Scrolling).

I don't know much about javascript or jQuery. I was searching about jscroll but can't figure out how to use it due to lack of knowledge.

Sorry if my language is bad. Any help with a demo if possible is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use an SPA fw like AngularJS/React.js if you want to develop a Single Page Application which does what you are looking for. 

Otherwise, you can return the HTML of the view from your controller and remove the existing view from your page using jquery and append the new one using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Infinite Scroll could help you with that.

https://github.com/metafizzy/infinite-scroll

Step 1: Implement the js in your *.blade.php (where you load jquery and so on... after including jquery of course)

step 2: add, e.g. `<section>` in you `<body>`-Tag.

Step 3: include js:

```
var infScroll = new InfiniteScroll('body', {
... use options as required...
});
```

https://github.com/metafizzy/infinite-scroll